# Is it possible to create a Scheduled Rule from CloudWatch for a Lambda State Function Set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

I want to use CloudFormation to create a stack of preexisting Lambda Functions into a State Machine using Step Functions on a schedule (30 mins). I have successfully created the stack for my other methods.

In essence, I need help or guidance on how to create a scheduled event in CloudFormation **for Step Functions**. Here is what I have been trying:

```
"NOTDScheduler": {
        "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "Schedules a NOTD every 30 minutes",
            "ScheduleExpression": "rate(30 minutes)",
            "State": "ENABLED",
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Arn": "${statemachineARN}",
                    "statemachineARN": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "NOTDStateMachine",
                            "Arn"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Id": "NOTDScheduleTarget"
                }
            ]
        },
```

But I keep getting errors such as

> [Error] /Resources/NOTDScheduler/Properties/Targets/0/statemachineARN/Fn::GetAtt: Resource type AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine does not support attribute {Arn}.

and have no clue how Arn isnt a supported attribute. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 8):

To get the ARN of a `AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine` resource you need to call `!Ref NOTDStateMachine` instead of `!GetAtt NOTDStateMachine.Arn`

Check `Return Values` here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine.html

Comment: Did this work? The documentation also points that it's valid to get the Arn using GetAttr function.

Comment: @KennethJ.SanchezVenegas back in the days (2017, wow long time ago) there wasn't the support to use `!GetAtt NOTDStateMachine.Arn` and the `!Ref` solution works pretty good. I believe AWS added the support of `!GetAtt` at some point.